# Stop working when running

Tags: c++

i wrote this code for my university project but it stop working when i try to run it.
can any one please help me where the problem is?
i guess its the pointers but i dont know where its wrong
for t and z if u want to try it use 20 and 5
and when i enter them it stop working instead of giving me outputs
it should give 2 .txt file including some numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    int z;
    double deltaz;
    double deltat;
    double beta;
    double mv=0;

    ofstream out1("Time-setllment.txt");
    ofstream out2("isochrones.txt");

    cout<<"Enter time step(>9&integer only):";
    cin>>t;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter height step(integer only):";
    cin>>z;
    cout<<endl;
    double **u = new double * [z+1];
    for (int i=0;i<z;i++)
        u[i]=new double [t+1];
    double *s = new double [t+1];
    mv = (0.00000003*365*24*3600)/(2*10);
    deltaz = 20/z;
    deltat = 50/t;
    beta = (2*deltat)/(deltaz*deltaz);
    if (beta>0.5)
        cout<<"Beta is more than 0.5 :|"<<endl;
    else
    {
    for (int i=0;i<z+1;i++)
    {
        if (i==0 || i==z)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<t+1;j++)
                u[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            u[i][0]=70-3.5*(i*deltaz);
        }
    }
    for (int j=1;j<t;j++)
    {
        for (int i=1;i<z;i++)
        {
            u[i][j] = u[i][j-1]+beta*(u[i-1][j-1]+u[i+1][j-1]-2*u[i][j-1]);
        }
    }
    for (int j=1;j<t+1;j++)
    {
        double sigmau=0;
        for (int i=1;i<z;i++)
        {
            sigmau +=u[i][j];
        }
        s[j]=mv*(35*20-deltaz*((u[0][j]+u[z][j])/2+sigmau));
    }


    out1<<"Time \t Settlment \n";
    for (int j=1;j<t+1;j++)
    {
        out1<<j*deltat<<"\t"<<s[j]<<"\n";
    }
    out2<<"Depth \t";
    for (int j=0;j<t+1;j++)
    {
        out2<<"t(year)="<<j*deltat<<"\t";
    }
    out2<<"\n";
    for (int i=0;i<z+1;i++)
    {
        out2<<i*deltaz<<"\t";
        for (int j=0;j<t+1;j++)
        {
            out2<<u[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<z+1;i++)
        delete []u[i];
    delete []u;
    delete []s;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "stops working"? Does it rash? Does it hang/block? Have you step through it with a debugger? If not, that would be a first step.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: it crashes after i entering the values.says ".exe has stopped working"

Comment: @kasra shamsaee run it in the debugger and you can get more info as to *why* it has "stopped working".

Comment: segmentation fault at line 42 which would be this part if (i==0 || i==z)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<t+1;j++)
                u[i][j] = 0;

        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in data allocation:

```
double **u = new double * [z+1];
for (int i=0;i<z;i++)
```

You actually want to change this to:

```
double **u = new double * [z+1];
for (int i=0;i<z+1;i++)
```